# Viewing the data without any background imagery in Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesium

Is there a way to completely disable the background imagery in cesium? I would like to see only my data without any background imagery. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to set both `baseLayerPicker` and `imageryProvider` to `false`.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    baseLayerPicker: false,
    imageryProvider: false
});
```